# I am trying to remove items from an array of objects used as projectiles for players or enemies to shoot in games made with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, canvas, foreach

I am practicing with making players and enemies for 2d games using vanilla JavaScript and HTML Canvas. The only problem I have is that I am trying to remove the projectiles from the playerProjectiles array when the projectile goes off of the screen. This is so that the game doesn't have to keep track of a bunch of projectiles that are not even on the screen, so the game will run smoother. I have tried sifting through the array using .forEach and splicing the current projectile that it is looping through as long as that projectile is off the screen. However, using this method, if there are multiple projectiles on the screen and one of them goes off of the screen, the entire array gets spliced and all of the projectiles are removed. What am I doing wrong here? Also, would it be better to put the code for the different mechanics of the projectiles in a different function? Etc. moving the projectiles up when they are shot out, actually drawing them to the screen, splicing them from the array when they go off the screen.

```js
function populatePlayerProjectilesArray() {
    playerProjectiles.forEach(projectile => {
        projectile.draw();
        projectile.y -= pdy;
        if(projectile.y <= 0 - projectile.rad) {
            playerProjectiles.splice(projectile)
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)**

Examples:

```
splice(start)
splice(start, deleteCount)
```

> **deleteCount** *Optional* An integer indicating the number of elements in the array to remove from start. If deleteCount is omitted [...], then all the elements from start to the end of the array will be deleted.

I think you want to change your splice statement to:

```
playerProjectiles.splice(projectile, 1)
```